# NiFi Invoke Http processor to get token and refresh

Tags: oauth-2.0, apache-nifi

I am using NiFi invokeHttp processor to send the data to some other third party server. 
The third party server is oauth2 protected, so I need to login and get the JWT token after getting it, invoke http needs to add it in header **'Authorization:"JWTtoken"'** before sending to third-party server and refresh it when it expires.

When I went through NiFi invokehttp processor it does not have any option for oauth2 flow options.

During search I got few links [oauth-template](https://gist.github.com/pvillard31/c2926fdcff57b017a771d2d1acdb5cba), this is very big flow to get a token which is adding more nifi processor stuffs ,
And [this](https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/2085) link shows there is some Jira ticket on the same but I could not find same in recent NiFi. Hence is there a better flow to handle oauth2 when sending the data to other third party server.

Comment: executescript? if you familiar with spring-security you could use executeGroovyScript to run groovy/java code

Comment: You mean calling a script from nifi processors?

Comment: Right. There is an  executegroovyscript processor that gives you ability to code oauth flow if you familiar with java or groovy. You tagged your question with spring-security that's why I suggest you it.

Comment: I have already implemented in spring boot and that gets the token. Now I want my Nifi invokeHttp to read from that service and Add it in header.

Comment: Use dynamic parameters for invokeHttp and add `Authentication` property with correct value, or if you stored token into an `Authentication` flow file attribute then use `Attributes to Send` in invokeHttp to add it to the request